# Code igniter batch_insert

Tags: codeigniter

I have an issue where I want to make a survey app where questions are retrieved from the database and looped in a form with radio buttons where by on submission I get a multi dimensional array.  Could some one help with the process of doing such a process. From form to controller and then to the model?

Here is my method

```
public function registerSelfAdmin(){
         $fieldsData = $this->db->field_data('response');
          foreach ($fieldsData as $key => $field){
            $datacc = array(  $field->name => $this->input->post($field->name) );
            $this->db->insert('response', $datacc);

          }
          return ($this->db->affected_rows() != 1) ? false : true;

         // $query=$this->db->insert_batch('response',$newData,'question_id');
         // return ($this->db->affected_rows() != 1) ? false : true;
    }
```

Comment: what is in `$fieldsData`

Comment: It's the multidimensional array containing post data

Comment: print r and post the array